# how to read config from xml in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hi I use Silverlight 3 and .net 3.5

I have a config file in xml which is the the following format

```
<applicationlist>
<application>
    <el1>test1</el1>
    <el2>http://localhost/1</el2>
    <el3>http://localhost/2</el3>
    <el4>http://localhost/3</el4>
</application>
</applicationlist>
```

I want to store this config file in the host web application and read from the silverlight application. But since silverlight has many access restrictions, i could not achieve this. Any idea how i can proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ultimately used the approach mentioned here

http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/loading_xml_sl2_pg1.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the xml file is in the same domain as your silverlight application you can load the xml using the [XmlReader.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf(v=VS.95).aspx) method.

Note that if the xml file is not on the same domain, make sure you add a [clientaccesspolicy.xml file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx) to you domain.